# Adobe Analytics Click Map

Tags: adobe-analytics

I'm trying to find out if the Adobe Analytics click map plugin fails because it is ancient und apparently not maintained, or if I need to change something in my (not up to date, but not quite as ancient -  H.27 ) s_code.

Now the instructions say "requires IE6 or FF3", so there is a good chance the plugin has died of old age without Adobe taking notice.

But then the [documentation](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/user/clickmap_get_started.html) says

> The Page ID (ClickMap) and Object ID (ClickMap) variables must be
>   present within a given image request after you click on at least one
>   link. These variables are also known as the pid and oid variables.
>   Generally, if s.trackInlineStats is set to true, these will
>   automatically populate

and while s.trackInlineStats is set to true I do not see a "pid" or "oid" parameter in the server calls.  So my question is: Are there any other changes I need to make to the s_code to get the thing working, or is this broken and won't work no matter what I do ?

The error I'm getting is "invalid address" and a description of what an url is supposed to look like. I'm using Firefox (albeit not Version 3 but the lastest version) and I am logged in to the Adobe account connected to that page.

Comment: There is a new plugin called Activity Map that has replaced Click Map and based on the new April 2016 release from Adobe they're saying that they will support Click Map for a limited period of time so I am not sure if that time has already come. More info https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/analytics/activitymap/activitymap-faq.html and https://files.acrobat.com/a/preview/f0f64c6f-4e01-4edf-a5e7-e6ca795abc30

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've come across several scenarios where it broke AA tracking. Weirdness that involved things like the plugin appending "undefined" to certain various url params in the AA request, some of them causing Adobe servers to reject the hit (for example, one case was it appended "undefined" to `currencyCode` value and if you do not have a valid currency code value, *Adobe rejects the entire hit*).

I've gone to Adobe ClientCare several times over ClickMap shenanigans and eventually I was told (by Adobe) to not use the plugin, because it's always been buggy, and they basically stopped supporting it a long time ago.

As @sky pointed out, Adobe recently released their new ActivityMap reports and plugin, but it does require you to upgrade to AppMeasurement 1.6+

Comment: We willl have to convince the client to upgrade, then. It seems like a good idea in any case.

Comment: Okay, finally got a response from client care - "don't use click map, use ActivityMap".

Comment: @EikePierstorff yeah.. we've been actively pushing all our clients to upgrade to AppMeasurement for a while now. I don't think H code (at least more recent versions anyways) will outright stop working any time soon, but Adobe has already (mostly) stopped pushing updates to H code, so I figure it's only a matter of time before Adobe stops offering.any kind of support for it.

Comment: There's 4000 lines of bespoke javascript code depending on the s_code (not my idea), so the client is a bit nervous about updating. But I think this is the point where we can convince him :-) Thank you again.